# High CPU Usage on SQL Server Caused by SqlCacheDependency

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cpu-usage, sqlcachedependency

We are experiencing an issue where our sql server where cpu usage jumps to and remains at 100% until the site is taken down and restarted.  We have gone through the code and optimized everything we can, and this is still happening.

What we do with cache is run a query that loads an entire structure (~6000 rows) from sql server, store that in cache, and query that cache to perform the various operations we need to perform throughout the rest of the application (there are a lot of recursive operations that need to be performed on the data and it would be a huge hit to the sql server otherwise).

I describe the above because it seems that when sql cache dependency is used, we encounter the cpu spike on the sql server.  If it is disabled, we no longer encounter the spike (on the sql server or the web server) even though we are still caching the same amount of data.

Does anyone have any idea what about sql cache dependency could cause behavior like this?
The sql server used is SQL Server 2008 R2.  The web server is IIS 7.5 and we used ASP.NET 3.5.  This web servers are set up as a cluster (x2), and they both point to the same sql server.

This is the code that loads/sets up the cache:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    cn.Open();

    string query =
        @"SELECT 
            id, 
            parentid, 
            field1, 
            field2, 
            field3, 
            field4, 
            field5
        FROM 
            dbo.theTableWithDataInIt";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
    cmd.Notification = null;
    cmd.NotificationAutoEnlist = true;
    SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableNotifications(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    if (!SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.GetTablesEnabledForNotifications(
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
         .Contains("dbo.theTableWithDataInIt"))
    {
        SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableTableForNotifications(
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].
        ConnectionString, "dbo.theTableWithDataInIt");
    }

    SqlCacheDependency dependency = new SqlCacheDependency(cmd);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //
    // Get Cache Data is a function that returns a DataSet with the data to be added to cache
    //
    Cache.Insert("mycache", GetCacheData(), dependency);
}
```

Comment: Is your table "theTableWithDataInIt" being updated?  Have you run a SQL Profiler trace to determine what the query activity is?

Comment: There is an admin portion to the application where the data can be updated.  But this shouldnt happen enough to cause a sustained cpu spike which required bringing down the site to get it under control.  We looked at the profiler, but this revealed nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: We did, but nothing stuck out as being the culprit.  Also, if that were the case it would be happening even with sql dependency turned off.

Comment: did you check for query recompilations (often a cause of high CPU)?

Comment: Recompilations happen every so often (as a result of an app pool expiring, copying files to bin/app_code, etc.).  But those would cause the spike on the web server, not the sql server wouldnt they?

Comment: Take a look at Activity Monitor in SSMS connected to the instance, and look at the Recent Expensive Queries, look for high ms/sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was resolved.  It turns out the indexes somehow became corrupt or lost.  Right clicking on the index in the table and selecting "Rebuild" solved the problem.